# Append li after current li

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to append a li in a ul after my current selection.

I bound a click event to the li, and when it's clicked, another li has to be added after the current.

What I have now is:

```
$(this).parent().append('<li>test</li>');
```

But this just adds the li to the ul, not after the current li.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the quite aptly-named [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after) method:

```
$(this).after('<li>test</li>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) and pass your `this` as the argument.